# How to install UC Browser in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I want to install UC Browser in Ubuntu 16.04 as I'm using it from last 4 years in Java, Android, Windows & ?(Linux). It even allows me to turn on wireless hotspot while still using the same WLAN adapter, that's why I prefer it over other browsers.

Comment: UC Browser is not available for Ubuntu at this time.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/839700/553971) to the Duplicate Question

Answer (score 3):

UC Browser is not available for Ubuntu or Linux in general.

What you can do is install android x86 http://www.android-x86.org/ in a VM and install UC Browser in it.

Answer (score 2):

UC Browser not support linux distros, if you want to turn on your notebook as wireless hotspot server you can turn it from system settings.

**system settings -> network -> use as hotspot**

Comment: This is not guranteed to work. Some Network cards may not support it

Comment: To use it as a Hotspot one should not be connected through his wireless adapter/card but I'm connected to Wifi and at the same time I want to use it as Hotspot. That's not possible.
But it may be possible if I'm using Dongle, Ethernet or USB Tehtering etc.